# Set Sound Settings to 152% on Boot (LMDE)

Tags: debian, linux-mint, audio, alsa

I have installed Linux Mint Debian Edition and everything is working correctly, except that 100% sound setting is not ideal on my speakers, so I see that I can increase it to 152% from my sound settings. **The problem is** that every time I reboot, it sets itself to 100%, and I manually have to increase to 152%. At first it wasn't my main concern, now it's the only inconvenience I have on my system.

**Q: How to do I set sound to 152% on boot?**

`amixer` value of 100% on GUI is 65536 on terminal.
`amixer` value of desired 153% is 99957 on terminal.

Outputs:

Setting 100% on GUI and Type `amixer` on terminal:

```
    Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

Setting 153% on GUI and Type `amixer` on terminal:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 99957 [153%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 99957 [153%] [on]
```

**Update:**

I now need to know how to set this command `amixer set 'Master' ,99957` on startup, as a startup script. Googling seems to produce somethings beyond my scope of knowledge. Step by step on creating startup scripts would help.

Comment: *This one goes to 11!* ;)

Comment: Nice Spinal Tap reference. This one's more like 15.

Comment: Enjoy yourselves, guys.

Comment: Your "updated" question about using a start-up script should be a separate question -- on debian just adding lines to `/etc/rc.local` should work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- set your desired value with `amixer set Master [100 | any other value]` or `amixer set 'Master',99957` (*as you have found out for yourself*)
- then force store the setting of the volume control with `alsactl store`(*make sure you are root*)

Comment: I have been with Windows for over 18 years (unfortunately), and with Linux for a month!
How exactly do I do that, lol?

Comment: Oh, OK. Run the terminal/console type in `sudo amixer set Master 152`, enter your root (super user) password. Then run the second command `sudo alsactl store`, enter your root (super user) password again. Reboot. Done.

Comment: I ran the first command with "99957" since this equal the 152% on the GUI (no sudo needed), Output:

=======>

Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
<========

But there's a problem, these values (65536) correspond to 100%, I clearly input 99957 to set it to 152% but it doesn't set. I know this because when I set the GUI to 152% and run amixer command it outputs this: (next comment)

Comment: Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 99957 [153%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 99957 [153%] [on]

Comment: You need `sudo` for `alsactl store`. Try `amixer set Master 152%`

Comment: Tried both. Also tried the obvious: setting 153% on GUI then ran terminal and ran `sudo alsactl store`, rebooted, still boots on 100%

Comment: OK, try setting it below 100% like 80%, execute `sudo alsactl store` and reboot. I think this might be a Mint only bug where you cannot set it above 100%.

Comment: Just modified your first command and it worked: `amixer set 'Master' ,99957` now it sets it to 153%, then ran the force store command but still doesn't persist on reboot!

Comment: Try the reduction I suggested. Also try setting it via gui and then save it with `alsactl store`. Must be a Mint bug.

Comment: yup, I tried that earlier, I can set it below 100% but not above. I'm now looking to run the command `amixer set 'Master' ,99957` as a startup script, I'm googling how to set startup scripts and I appreciate if you could help. Plus, **please change your answer to the modified first command so I can set it as Best answer**.